# Doubts about get method and passing parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

In the **routes.rb** file

```
get 'commands/deleteuser/' => 'commands#delete_user', as: :delete_user
```

In the view

```
<%= link_to "Delete", delete_user_path(:user_id => user.id, :command_id => @command.id), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

In this way I can call from the action (and it works)

`user = User.find(params[:user_id])`

My question is: is it right to get in this way? I mean the `get` method shows all the attribute in the url but in the way I used they are all hidden. So is it right to use a get method? Second where are they stored if in the url they are not visible?

Where are the params stored in this case if I don't see then in the url?

**routes.rb**

```
FwLab::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'commands/deleteuser/'            => 'commands#delete_user',          as: :delete_user
  patch 'users/:id/changeadmin'         => 'users#changeadmin',             as: :changeadmin
  post 'commands/execute'               => 'commands#execute',              as: :execute
  get 'commands/:id/userslist'          => 'commands#users_list',           as: :list
  get 'commands/:id/adduserindex'       => 'commands#add_user_index',       as: :add_user_index
  post 'commands/adduser'               => 'commands#user_add',             as: :user_add

  resources :users,    only: [:create, :edit, :update, :index, :destroy]
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :commands, only: [:index, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]



  root 'sessions#new'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',     via: 'delete'
  match '/home',    to: 'commands#index',       via: 'get'
end
```

Comment: what users you need to delete? only current (like "delete my profile") or any (like in admin mode)?

Comment: No no, all is working, that's not the problem. I would like to know if it is the right way, call a get method with params not visible in the url

Comment: POST (DELETE). get params ARE always visible in url..

Comment: and another advice: do not use `User.find` (for deleting especially). use `@command.users.where(id: params[:user_id])`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. what's the difference? where can I find more info about that?

Comment: in your case it will be possible to change param :user_id to any and delete any user. in my case relation `@command.users` will scope only current `@command`'s users available for deleting

Comment: @antox is `commands` a model, ie. do you have a `Command` class in app/models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actions / links that change something, especially destructive ones, should not be made available through GET. This is dangerous, because for example search engines that crawl your website could follow such a link and accidentally delete a user.

In this case, you should use HTTP DELETE. To do so,

- change your route to

  ```
  delete 'commands/deleteuser' => 'commands#delete_user', as: :delete_user
  ```
- in your link helper, add the method attribute

  ```
  <%= link_to "Delete", delete_user_path(:user_id => user.id, :command_id => @command.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
  ```

There are two ways parameters can be passed from browser to server with a request:

1. as query string parameters, that is, as part of the URL, e.g. example.com?param=value
2. as part of the request body

Your browser transmits a lot of data to the server with each interaction (clicking a link, submitting a form etc.) that is usually invisible to you. Take a look at the developer tools built into your browser to make them visible. Here is a screenshot from Chromes developer tools:

[image: Screenshot from Chromes developer tools]

This is a POST request, something you usually see for example when submitting a form. The data that would be appended to the URL in a GET request is visible here under "Form Data".

Comment: Thanks. Another question, I used a get method so the attributes should be visible in the url but so it is not..so where are they stored?

Comment: show full routes.rb. i guess you have something like `resources :users` and it overrides your get method

Comment: @okliv I think antox GET method works fine. He was wondering whether it was a good idea to use GET.

Comment: @antox I have updated my answer with an explanation where the parameters go.